# getting error while comparing two check boxes in vba macro

Tags: excel, vba, loops, checkbox, password-protection

I have two checkboxes, the first checkbox is associated with first-person and the second checkbox is associated with the second person who is a reviewer. When checkboxes are checked, it should fetch the user name and the current time. Also, When only first checkbox is checked, sheet will be not be protected but if the second checkbox is checked, sheet should get protected. this is working fine.

but if I want to put some conditions as below, it is giving error.

Comment: "giving error" is not a useful description of whatever problem you're having.  Please update your question with a description of what happens when your code runs.

Comment: @TimWilliams code works fine when each checkbox is checked and unchecked. it fetches the date and username flawlessly. However, when I try to compare the state of two checkboxes and put the conditions (as mentioned 3 points in question) , it does not work. condition is there in last 8 line of the code. that part is not running. I am bit new to macro, any kind of help will be very appreciated. thank you

Comment: Do you get any error, or it just doesn't do what you expect?  does it do something else instead?  In short, what tells you it's not working?  FYI your With blocks are not doing anything - they're supposed to scope the contained code, but none of the code has the leading `.` to connect it to the `With` object

Comment: If the user runs `checkboxnew2` before `checkboxnew1` then cb1 is not set to anything.  Is there only the single pair of checkboxes on the worksheet?

Comment: No it does not give any error. Add two checkboxes in excel and assign macro checkboxNew1() to first checkbox and checkboxNew2() to the second checkbox. Now when you check and uncheck the checkboxes, individually code will work. but I want to compare the state of those two checkboxes and on the basis of that I want the result, this si not working

Comment: yes, there is only single pair of checkboxes in a sheet. I am very new to VBA so tried to write code in my way, maybe this is wrong. please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I used two checkboxes named "chk_1" and "chk_2", both linked to the macro below.

```
Sub CheckBoxClicked()

    Const PW As String = "c1tc0"
    Const COL_NM As Long = 3
    Const COL_TM As Long = 4

    Dim cb1 As CheckBox, cb2 As CheckBox
    Dim cb1Row As Long, cb2Row As Long, cb1Checked As Boolean, cb2Checked As Boolean
    Dim cb1Clicked As Boolean, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Set cb1 = ws.CheckBoxes("chk_1")
    cb1Row = cb1.TopLeftCell.Row
    cb1Checked = cb1.Value = xlOn

    Set cb2 = ws.CheckBoxes("chk_2")
    cb2Row = cb2.TopLeftCell.Row
    cb2Checked = cb2.Value = xlOn

    cb1Clicked = (Application.Caller = cb1.Name)

    ws.Unprotect PW 'default is unprotected

    'handle data entry/clearing
    If cb1Clicked Then
        ws.Cells(cb1Row, COL_NM).Value = IIf(cb1Checked, Environ("USERNAME"), Null)
        ws.Cells(cb1Row, COL_TM).Value = IIf(cb1Checked, Now, Null)
    Else
        ws.Cells(cb2Row, COL_NM).Value = IIf(cb2Checked, Environ("USERNAME"), Null)
        ws.Cells(cb2Row, COL_TM).Value = IIf(cb2Checked, Now, Null)
    End If

    'implement your protection rules here...
    If cb1Checked And cb2Checked Then
        ws.Protect PW
    ElseIf cb1Checked And Not cb2Checked Then
        'no reprotect?
    ElseIf Not cb1Checked And cb2Checked Then
        ws.Protect PW
    ElseIf Not cb1Checked And Not cb2Checked Then
        'no reprotect
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for quick reply. However, this is giving error in this line -

Set cb1 = ws.CheckBoxes("chk_1") 

is it working for you?

Comment: Did you name your checkboxes "chk_1" and "chk_2" ?

Comment: what do you mean? I assigned this macro directly to my checkbox by  --> right-click, assign macro. I did like this before and assigned checkboxnew1() to first checkbox and checkboxnew2() to second checkbox

Comment: But did you name your checkboxes?  Select each one and you can set the name in the "name" box then press enter.

Comment: sorry for asking silly question. i changed the name of the checkboxes as "chk_1" and "chk_2" , however i am still getting the error.

Comment: What error are you getting ? - I can't guess...  You only need the one macro - assign both your checkboxes to it.

Comment: run-time error '1004':
The item with specified name wasn't found. 
i am getting this on code "Set cb1 = ws.CheckBoxes("chk_1")"

Comment: yes i've assigned CheckBoxClicked() to both the checkboxes and named chk_1 and chk_2 to the checkboxes, but getting above runtime error.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what to say - it works for me.  I will post a sample workbook in a little while and drop the link here.

Comment: Example - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I_qhDszav5kKjVnX5dvNW4-9mWzWvklx

Comment: Thank you Tim. It worked like a charm. sorry for simple questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. I placed two ActiveX Checkboxes in a worksheet. The reason I used ActiveX controls is that they have events, meaning code is triggered when they are clicked without assigning a macro to them. I removed their captions and named them *ChkOwner* and *ChkManager*. They are placed in the column to the left of the *Name* field which, in turn is to the left of the Date/Time field (easy to adjust: look for *Offset* in the code).

The code must be placed in the code sheet belonging to the tab on which you want the action. Please be sure to select the correct sheet because elsewhere the code will have no effect.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    SetProtection
End Sub

Private Sub ChkOwner_Click()
    SignTheDocument ChkOwner
End Sub

Private Sub ChkManager_Click()
    SignTheDocument ChkManager
    SetProtection
End Sub


Private Sub SignTheDocument(Chk As MSForms.CheckBox)

    Chk.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = IIf(Chk.Value, Application.UserName, vbNullString)
    Chk.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = IIf(Chk.Value, Now(), vbNullString)
End Sub

Private Sub SetProtection()

    With ActiveSheet
        If ChkManager.Value = True Then
            .Protect Password:="Secret", _
                     Contents:=True, _
                     UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        Else
            Unprotect "Secret"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The first procedure runs when the worksheet is activated. It calls the procedure `SetProtection`. Here you can specify the protection object in great and easy detail. The item I added is `UserInterfaceOnly = True`. It means that code can make changes to the the user can't do from the worksheet interface. If you want to keep the password secret add password protection to your VBA project. That is different and separate from the worksheet and workbook protection, set from the VB Editor window.

The next two procedures respond to clicks on the check boxes in the worksheet. They both call the sub `SignTheDocument` to whom they identify themselves. The signature is added or removed depending upon the value of the check box. If the click was on the *ChkManager* protection will also be reviewed.

Simple and easy. I think you can handle it.

Comment: thank you. can it be done with simple checkbox? I need to use that

Comment: In the example I built here on my PC it was done. I just rebuilt the screen shot you posted on a blank sheet - two ActiveX check boxes really -  attached the code and tested. You should do the same and see where the entries are made. I have some small doubts on the protection, like what will happen if the workbook is saved (or not saved), closed and re-opened. I didn't test that. But those are matters of the protection, not of the check boxes.

Comment: no worries. code suggested by TIm above worked :) thank you for your help once again.